# How do you get a conditional statement to branch?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am working on a question for my Computer Programming class in high school and the question is as follows.

Using a conditional statement, generate a program in any coding language and explain the working of it: “If the temperature of your room is more than 80° or less than or equal to 60°, then the program should branch; otherwise, the execution should continue without branching.”

I have managed to create a conditional statement on my own, but I do not understand the branching part. I have Googled already and have found nothing useful. Can someone explain what I am supposed to do?

**Also, I chose JavaScript for my coding language.

```
function temperature(z) {
  if(z > 80 || z <= 60) { 
  /*branch program?*/;
  }
  else {
  /*do not branch program?*/;
  }
  }
  console.log(temperature(81)); /*evaluates to branching*/
```

That is all I have so far. Also, is there a simpler way to write that code? I would love some opinions!

Comment: please add your statement as well.

Comment: "the program should branch" simply means if you were to visualize "paths" your CPU could take through the program, there are branches wherever there are two different pieces of code that could be executed next depending on some condition. whenever you write an if-statement, the code inside the braces only gets executed if the condition is true - it's a branch of the program that might be skipped over.

Answer (score 1):

The *if* statement itself is a *branching* instruction to your CPU where in assembly language CPU would’ve taken that instruction as a possibility to skip set of instructions inside the *if* statement and continue after it (*branching*) or execute that piece of code within the *normal* flow.
I believe that the statement you wrote is already a perfect example of the question, you should just be able to change some variable inside that *if* where that exact variable would’ve taken different value if the program were to take different execution path (aka *branch*).

---

**Edit:**

You could end up with code looking something like this:

```
function getTemperatureFeel(t) {
  var feel = "Perfect"; // this is straight execution
  if (t > 80 || t <= 60) { 
    feel = "Either warm or cold"; // this is branch execution
  }

  return feel;
}

console.log(getTemperatureFeel(81));
```

Comment: The code in your edit I would describe as incorrect. The problem states that if the condition is met, "the execution should continue **without branching**". This to me indicates that the code should flow in a straight line, and might take a branch, but otherwise should continue as if nothing happened - which is not exactly what is described by your use of an `else` block.

Comment: I believe the problem rather states that if the condition is met - then do branch, otherwise - continue straight. (from the OP *“If the temperature of your room is more than 80° or less than or equal to 60°, then the program should branch; otherwise, the execution should continue without branching.”*)

Comment: Exactly, I don't define an if/else as having a "straight" path, more like it splits into two paths going different directions before rejoining. Versus having a branch that rejoins the "straight" path, as in an if with no else.

Comment: This is an important distinction because, in assembly, an if/else takes two jump instructions (two branches) whereas just an if takes only one.

Comment: You might be right - *else* seems as branching as an *if*. I will edit the code and get rid of *else* statement.